# CSS class or partial id based Anchor Tag Specificity

Tags: css, css-specificity

I have a table with a column having anchor tag for each row. There are multiple style classes already applied in this anchor tag. I want to change color of the link.

I tried the following things-

1. I specified a specific class for link color and tried applying it at as the last style class in the "class" attribute. It did not work. Even I tried using `a.link-color` ( `.link-color` is the class ) or `.link-color a` , but it did not work.
2. I tried using `!important`. It worked, but `!important` is not a good idea.
3. I tried using `id` to style the color and it worked. However, it is not good to have all the anchor tag elements in the table having the same `id` attribute.
4. I tried using the partial id match (matching the beginning characters - as `a[id^="linkcolor"]` or simply `[id^="linkcolor"]`, but it did not work.

The only approach for me is either [1] or [4]. However, they did not work. Whereas [2] and [3] worked, but they are not the good solution.

How can I increase the specificity of the class in approach [1] or the partial selector attribute of approach [4] so that I can get the desired result?

The default color is coming from one of those classes which are already there. They are maintained by the third party, so we don't have any access or control on them. Inline styling is absolutely out of question.

Comment: You need to post a [mcve]

Comment: If you inspect you link (using the inspector), which css selector overwrite the css that your are written?

Comment: The best way to ensure specificity is to override the same class/compound class with your stylesheet which comes after the styles you are overriding.

Comment: Could you please provide a code simple it will make it easier for us to help you. Also please provide all the css that overriding your classes.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding parents and grand parents. Not best practice but it seems like you don't have the luxury of using best practice right now :)

Something in the line of

```
tbody > tr:nth-child(6) > td:nth-child(1) > link > a
```

You can use Chome dev tool, select the element and choose copy -> copy selector.